# If $A,B$ have the same $4$ fundamental subspaces, then what can we say about $A$ and $B$? (Gilbert Strang's lecture on YouTube)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

https://youtu.be/l88D4r74gtM?t=2358

Let $A, B$ be $m\times n$ matrices.
If $A,B$ have the same null space, the same row space, the same column space and the same left null space, then what can we say about $A$ and $B$?

My answer was "$A$ and $B$ have the same reduced row echelon form".
But if $A,B$ have the same null space, then $A$ and $B$ have the same reduced row echelon form.
So, I think that Strang's answer in his head is different from my answer and it must be stronger than my answer.

Comment: Please ask a standalone question that is complete without requiring external resources such as the video you linked. What are A and B supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer only guarantees same row space and nullspace. Just try simple examples. Here’s one:
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1&1\\ 0&0\end{matrix}\right] \quad\text{and}\quad \left[\begin{matrix} 1&1\\ 2&2 \end{matrix}\right]$$

P.S. You didn’t watch my lectures (or digest my text) on this! … So, does Strang ever give an answer, other than saying his TF question is stupidly F?

Comment: Professor Theodore Shifrin, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: If you don't have follow-up questions, please accept the answer so that this question will not continue on the "unanswered" list.